# What happens when two same type semiconductiors are joined togehther?

Tags: semiconductors, pn-junction

If we join two n-type semiconductors with different doping concentrations (for example doping concentrations are 4x10^15 and 10^15 per cubic centimeter), what will happen? Will there be a depletion region at the junction? What will the depletion width be if so happens?